# How to place a defined variable at multiple locations

Tags: tikz-pgf, variable, definition

I would like to use the defined variable - \arrows[#1] - from this tikz example:

https://texample.net/tikz/examples/overlapping-arrows/

```
% Overlapping arrows
% Author: Elena Botoeva
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.3cm, paperwidth=3.3cm, paperheight=3.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: Overlapping arrows
:Tags: Shadows;Decorative Drawings
:Author: Elena Botoeva
:Slug: overlapping-arrows
\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.1,0.1}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.2,0.6,0.2}

\def\arrow{
  (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) arc (6.25:120:1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:0.9) [rounded corners=1] -- (130:1.1) [rounded corners=0.5] --
  (120:1.3) [sharp corners] -- (120:1.2) arc (120:5.25:1.2)
  [rounded corners=1] -- (10.75:1.1) -- (6.5:1) -- cycle
}

\tikzset{
  ashadow/.style={opacity=.25, shadow xshift=0.07, shadow yshift=-0.07},
}

\def\arrows[#1]{         
  \begin{scope}[scale=#1]
    \draw[color=darkred, %
    drop shadow={ashadow, color=red!60!black}] \arrow;

    \draw[color=darkgreen, bottom color=green!90!black, top color=green!60, %
    drop shadow={ashadow, color=green!60!black}] [rotate=120] \arrow;

    \draw[color=darkblue, right color=blue, left color=blue!60, %
    drop shadow={ashadow, color=blue!60!black}] [rotate=240] \arrow;

    % to hide the green shadow
    \draw[color=darkred, left color=red, right color=red!60] \arrow;
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \arrows[1];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to do with it is draw multiple versions of the variable at specific locations in a tikz drawing, and I am not sure how to specify the locations.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Thanks, Barbara!  I have been "consumer" for many years, but this is my first posting!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the best or the most elegant way to do what I need, but here is what I came up with (`\redarrow` and `\bluearrow` are two different versions of the original in the example):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
  \redarrow[1];
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2cm,0cm)}]
  \bluearrow[1];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```